# Increase number if row value duped

Tags: sql

Sorry not sure how to example this by using words (that's why have an issue to find an answer)

I need that Sequence will increase the number if ID value is duped

```
ID          Sequence        Value
1111          0              234324
2222          0              23432
3333          0              324
3333          1              234
3333          2              432234
4444          0              23423
4444          1              234
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to start from 0, use this query:

```
select *, ROW_NUMBER()over( partition by id order by id)-1 from tbl
```

Answer (score 1):

You want `row_number()`.  Something like this:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by id order by id) as seqnum
from t;
```

Note:  the numbers will be incrementing, but the rows will not be in any particular order.

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  You data has no obvious ordering.  You can change the `order by` to get values in a particular order for a given `id`.